# StreamWriter.WriteLine() results in empty file

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files

I am trying to write several lines, one at a time, to a .txt file using StreamWriter.WriteLine (Not statically).

```
const string filename = "BasicTestInfo.txt";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 350 200 200 10 2 28 20 200 2500 1200 1 1", Player1);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 300 150 150 4 2 15 18 150 2500 1000 1 0", Player2);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 200 140 450 25 14 10 70 4500 2500 750 1 1", Player3);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 175 120 400 15 3 8 50 3000 2500 850 1 0", Player4);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 300 100 300 8 1 4 30 1000 2500 1200 1 0", Player5);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} 450 310 450 20 5 5 35 1500 2500 700 1 1", Player6);
        }
```

Each of the player objects are string cosntants.  If I run this with a different filename (a.k.a. BasicTestInfo2.txt) it creates that file in the bin.Debug, but it's empty.  I know that I am reaching the inside of the using block (I put a Console.WriteLine in there), and I know that I want to Truncate which is why I am using false for append (Although replacing the false with true or no parameter at all does not fix the problem).

The basic problem is that even though the file gets created, there are no lines of text in the file.

Comment: I have copied your code into fresh console application - and it works fine. Maybe you clean that file afterwards?

Comment: Use full path names for a file.  So not basictestinfo2.txt but c:\foo\bar\basictestinfo2.txt.  This ensures that you can always find the file back where you expect it to be.  Don't forget to use Environment.GetFolderPath() to get a reliable folder name to write to.

Comment: Does a previous debugging session have an open lock on that file still?

Comment: You might want to add a writer.Flish() at the end of your using-block to make sure the content of the stream is really written to the file.

Comment: @JleruOHeP What does clean the file mean?

Comment: @Hans Passant It needs to run in other environments so I'll try the GetFolderPath() one, but again, the files show up in the same directory when I try a new file name.

Comment: @Mithrandir
I believe that the using-block makes the Flush() function unnecessary because when the stream becomes closed, the stream gets flushed.  However, I have tried adding writer.Flush() to the end of the block and that did not solve the problem.

Comment: I meant, for example, that you have File.Create(filename); somewhere later... Can you add a breakpoint at the next statement after your using block and check file content?

Answer (score 15):

Yes it is true that in VB.net this (an exclusive flush) was not needed with the default settings but with C# you need a Writer.Flush call to force the write. Of course - Writer.Close() would force the flush as well. Alternatively we can set the AutoFlush Property of the StreamWriter instance:

```
sw.AutoFlush = true;
// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the StreamWriter 
// will flush its buffer to the underlying stream after every  
// call to StreamWriter.Write.
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that: the "using" construct will obviate an exclusive flush, but a lot of people are landing here just on the basis of subject of this question and this is the lowest hanging fruit when faced with the issue.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't address the question; the `Dispose()` method in `StreamWriter` will call `Flush()` and the code above will dispose of the writer at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: This answer must be incorrect. Disposing of a writer flushes all contents.

Comment: Setting `MyStreamWriter.AutoFlush = true;` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

close the writer

writer.close();

That workedfor me.

Comment: The `using` will close the writer.  You would only need to explicitly do this if you *didn't* have it inside of a `using`.

Answer (score 2):

The code shown looks fine.

If I had to guess, I'd suspect that there is an exception (perhaps from a dodgy `ToString` implementation on `Player`) that you are swallowing somewhere.

Step through the code to see what happens as you go over each successive `WriteLine`, and whether it goes all the way to the end of the `using` block without an error.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  I discovered my problem.  Because I want to overwrite the file every time I write to it instead of append it, I was building my FileStream with FileMode.Truncate (Before I switched to just using the StreamWriter constructor directly).  Now because of this I was accessing the file with a StreamReader built with Truncate.  Thus when I opened the file for reading, I was deleting all of it.  After replacing it with FileMode.OpenOrCreate, the file is not disrupted while opening and the test passes.  Thus we see the problem was not in writing, but in reading all along.

Answer (score -1):

I had similair problem.

I fixed it in this way, just put your string into String.Format():

```
writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} 350 200 200 10 2 28 20 200 2500 1200 1 1", Player1));
```